# node utils\updatebaseUri.js

Tags: nft, generative-art

I am not sure how to resolve this issue:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\steph\Downloads\hashlips_art_engine-1.1.2_patch_v1\hashlips_art_engine-1.1.2_patch_v1\utils\updatebaseUri.js'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
requireStack: []
```

Does anyone know what is that i need to fix make node utils\updatebaseUri.js work?

Answer (score 0):

Use this  node utils/update_info.js